# How can I get the OpenGL context from a window?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, opengl

I need to get the OpenGL Context (an `HGLRC`) from a window (or device context). The function `wglGetCurrentContext` cannot be used since I do not know whether or not the context is bound to the current thread. How can this be done?

Comment: The way you ask your question reeks of a XY problem (http://xyproblem.info). You have problem X, you think doing Y may help you get X solved, but you don't know Y either. Why are you asking Y. Just tell us X. _**What is is that you're actually trying to get done?**_

Comment: Why are there down votes and close votes on this question? It's a perfectly fine question. Just because there's no solution to the problem it doesn't make it an ill-formulated problem. It's something that'll eventually come up if you dive deeper into OpenGL window system integration details.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to get the OpenGL Context (an HGLRC) from a window (or device context).

You can't!

OpenGL render contexts are in *no* way tied to windows, at all.

Windows can have an arbitrary number of device contexts. There's at least one primary context, but additional contexts can be created at any time.

OpenGL render contexts can be made active on *any* device context (DC) that is compatible, but there is – again – no strict tie between a DC and a OpenGL context. As long as *any* given window's device context is compatible to a certain OpenGL context the OpenGL context can be made current on the device context. Later, if one desires so, that connection can be undone and the same OpenGL context can be made current on a different DC of a different window (as long as they're compatible).

Oh, and it also works the other way round: You can have an arbitrary number of threads, each having a different OpenGL context active on the same window/device context simultanously.

There simply is no bijective mapping between windows and OpenGL contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wglGetCurrentContext()` to check if there's a context currently bound. But there isn't any function that can be used to check whether a `HDC` is associated with a `HGLRC`.

These are the only functions in relation to getting each other:

```
HDC GetDC(HWND hWnd)
HWND WindowFromDC(HDC hdc)

// Depends on wglMakeCurrent()
HDC wglGetCurrentDC()
HGLRC wglGetCurrentContext()
```

So you'd need to keep track of the `HGLRC` after creating it.